# uname: what ioctl does it use?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, ioctl

Does anyone know if `uname()` makes an `ioctl()` call directly or indirectly?  I reviewed the source, however didn't see that it does.  I also used `strace` and did not see the kernel call made.

Thanks

```
strace uname                                                                                
execve("/usr/bin/uname", ["uname"], 0x7fffe60bef30 /* 35 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x559dc7796000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=161332, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 161332, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0c9384000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260A\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1820400, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0c9382000
mmap(NULL, 1832960, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0c91c2000
mprotect(0x7fd0c91e4000, 1654784, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7fd0c91e4000, 1339392, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x22000) = 0x7fd0c91e4000
mmap(0x7fd0c932b000, 311296, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x169000) = 0x7fd0c932b000
mmap(0x7fd0c9378000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b5000) = 0x7fd0c9378000
mmap(0x7fd0c937e000, 14336, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fd0c937e000
close(3)                                = 0
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7fd0c9383540) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd0c9378000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x559dc6f13000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7fd0c93d3000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7fd0c9384000, 161332)          = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x559dc7796000
brk(0x559dc77b7000)                     = 0x559dc77b7000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3031632, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3031632, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fd0c8edd000
close(3)                                = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="debian", ...}) = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "Linux\n", 6Linux
)                  = 6
close(1)                                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system call involved is … [`uname`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html)! You can see it in your trace:

```
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="debian", ...}) = 0
```

It provides the operating system name, release, version etc.

Answer (score 1):

From your strace:

```
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="debian", ...}) = 0
```

no ioctl at all. `uname` itself is  a syscall (on Linux), which takes an address of a struct that it fills in with system information.

`man 2 uname` has more details.